# Using LDAP Configuration parameters from Apache to other LDAP Clients

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

I have the following LDAP Configuration for APACHE. How do I Use this information into other LDAP clients.

```
    <Directory /opt/sites/MyAuthSite.V2/html*>
        Options ExecCGI
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AuthLDAPEnabled on
        AuthLDAPAuthoritative on
        AuthName  "MyAuth"
        AuthType  Basic
        AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.xyz.com:389/cn=Users,dc=abccorp,dc=com?samaccountname
        AuthLDAPBindDN "user@abc.com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword userpass
        require msSFU30PosixMemberOf cn=abc.com_g_mts,cn=users,dc=abccorp,dc=com
    </Directory>
```

I need to use this in Softerra LDAP Browser 4.5 (Free LDAP Explorer) & OpenERP[image]. But I do not know how to handle authentication part.I am attaching the screen shot of it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This section of your Apache Config answers your questions:

```
    AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.xyz.com:389/cn=Users,dc=abccorp,dc=com?samaccountname
    AuthLDAPBindDN "user@abc.com"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword userpass
```

So your host is ldap.xyz.com on port 389.

Your user's BindDN (and thus your principal) is user@abc.com and userpass as the password.

Now, probably user@abc.com as the principal won't work (depends on Softerra).  But your user is probably something like cn=user,cn=Users,dc=abccorp,dc=com based on how you are configured.

One hint to note, the cn=Users container is NOT an OU.  It is a container (cn=), which often confuses the heck out of folk starting with LDAP on AD.